# Replace invalid image url with 404 image, with custom size

Tags: image, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to return a default (404) image if requested image does not exist. I set the naming convention so that I can pull different sizes of the same image (which are pre-generated by my application).

```
foo-200.png
foo-50.png
foo-10.png
etc..
```

The number after the dash (-) is the size of the image requested. Again, once I upload an image, the system will automatically generate the different sizes.

However, if a request is made for an image which does not exist (eg. `bar-200.png`) I want to return a 404 image with the same size as the requested.

```
bar-200.png     (404)->    notfound-200.png
bar-50.png      (404)->    notfound-50.png
bar-10.png      (404)->    notfound-10.png
etc...
```

Here is what I have in my htaccess currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) notfound.png [NC,L]
```

But this only returns one size 404 image no matter what size was requested..

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^notfound-)^[^-]+-([0-9]+)\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ notfound-$1.png [L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you! Can you help me break down what's going on here so I can learn for future cases?

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. `(?!^notfound-)` is actually a negative lookahead regex that makes sure not to match rest of the URI if it starts from `/notfound-`. Then `[^-]+-([0-9]+)` matches 1 or more non hyphen characters then a hyphen and then 1 or more numbers (group #1). Rest is matching dot and valid image extensions. If match is successful then internally forward the request to `notfound-group1.png`.

Comment: Great explanation. I'd vote up but not enough rep :( Thanks a million!